# How to run a .class file that is part of a package from cmd?

Tags: java, class, cmd, package, javac

I keep getting errors when I make my `.class` part of a `package` and try to run it from cmd.

Here's the code that works after using `javac` and then java:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and then the code that does not work:

```
package com;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

giving me this error after trying to run the program via the command: `java HelloWorld`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong nam
e: com/HelloWorld)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Here's what I've tried doing so far:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
java -cp . com.HelloWorld
java -cp . com/HelloWorld
java HelloWorld
java com.HelloWorld
java com/HelloWorld
```

Keep in mind that `javac` returns with no errors and that simply removing `package com;` solves the problem. Sometimes in other scenarios I get an error that says the main class file cannot be found or something along those lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `HelloWord` live?  Does it live in the `com/` directory?

Comment: I think you do not have the folder "com".

Comment: It lives in a directory created by me C:\java in which are located HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class

Comment: Let me try renaming the directory to the package name and see what happens

Comment: The problem is now resolved. Turns out that I was using the java command from within the package folder and I had to cd backwards for it to work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Suppose you did `cd C:/projects` and `HelloWorld.class` is in `C:/projects/com`, then just type:

```
java com.HelloWorld
```

Comment: The file now resides in C:\com. When I try out your command it says:

Comment: Error: COuld not find or load main class com.HelloWorld

Comment: At that point you must be cd'd into C:\, not C:\com. In other words, you need to try running it from outside of the package directory.

Comment: But why should one run from outside. How can one run from inside?

Answer (score 17):

Packages are directly related to the expected directory location of the file.

That is, if you have a source file with the package directive of `com`, it is expected that the file will live in the `com` directory.

In your `HelloWorld` example, it would be expected that the `HelloWorld.java` file would be stored in the `com` directory, like `com\HelloWorld.java`

When you compile the file, it will create a class file called `HelloWorld.class` in the `com` directory, like `com\HelloWorld.class`

This way, when Java goes looking for the `com.HelloWorld` class, it would actually be searching it's class path and appending `com\HelloWorld.class` to it until it finds your class file or runs out of class path

**Example**

So, I copied your `HelloWorld.java` (with package) example to `C:\java\com\HelloWord.java`

From the command line, I changed to the `C:\java` directory...

```
C:\java>dir com
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is ####-####

 Directory of C:\java\com

09/08/2013  01:55 PM    <DIR>          .
09/08/2013  01:55 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/08/2013  01:55 PM               135 HelloWorld.java
```

Then I compiled the `HelloWorld.java`

```
C:\java>javac com\HelloWorld.java
```

Then I ran it...

```
C:\java>java com.HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

---

You might like to have a read through [Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) tutorial

Comment: The file now lives in C:\com. The problem is the same when I use "java HelloWorld" and when I try "java com.HelloWorld" like @sbat suggested it cannot find or load the main class.

Comment: Okay.  Did you try my example?  You could replace `C:\java\com` for `C:\com` because, as I demonstrated, it works fine...

Comment: there is a typo. You meant to say live but said life

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is:

```
java -classpath /path/to/package-folder <packageName>.<MainClassName>
```

So you may try: `java com.HelloWorld` which would expect `com/HelloWorld.class` file to be present as classpath by default points to the current directory (if not specified).

In case you're in different folder, try specifying *[classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))*:

```
$ CLASSPATH=/path/to/package-folder/ java com.HelloWorld
Hello World!
$ java -cp /path/to/package-folder/ com.HelloWorld
Hello World!
$ cd /path/to/package-folder/ && java com.HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

For further explanation, check: [How do I run Java .class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5757189/55075)

Answer (score 3):

Run the program from the parent directory of the **com** directory.

```
java com.HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 3):

When you compile the java code, use -d, in your case, it would be

```
javac -d . com.HelloWorld.java
```

After the above command, java compiler generate a folder named "com", under the "com" folder, you will see your HelloWorld.class

Then under the same folder as you run javac, run the following command

```
java com.HelloWorld
```

Comment: For me worked: javac -d HelloWord.java and then -> java com.HelloWorld

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the file locates at  C:/projects/com/HelloWorld 
and you can try the following ways.

1.`java -cp c:/projects com.HelloWorld`

2.`cd c:/projects`
   `java com.HelloWorld`
(The example 2 is not working in many situation,such as java process.)

if there is no package declaration and there will be a little change.

1.`java -cp c:/projects/com HelloWorld`

2.`cd c:/projects/com`
   `java HelloWorld`
(It's not good with the same reason.)

alternatively,relative path will be ok but has some risk.
Last remember put the class file in end of cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder named `com` under Java folder and put the `HelloWorld.java` into `com` folder. Then run again `javac` and `java`.

Answer (score 1):

There could be such a problem, when you are executing 'java' command directly from folder of your '*.class' files. This command should be executed from project 'parent' directory. All is well explained in the following article:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute directory or put your HelloWorld.class into ..\last_directory\com

```
1. java -cp .......\last_directory com.HelloWorld
2. java -cp .......\last_directory HelloWorld(with created com)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a -cp flag while running a java class , -cp needed while running a class or a main program from a binary (jar) file.
While running a main program from a command line you need to make sure you have the class in the same folder structure as package name in the java file, ex.

```
home/user/foo java com.test.className   

here classNmae class file and exist under home/user/foo/com/test
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution in Linux, same principle:

Say, the File is **`/work/packageName/file.java`**, with a first line:

```
package packageName;
```

**Under the working directory `/work/packageName/*`:**

`javac file.java` will **not** work, as long as `file.java` contain any reference to other files in that package.
The solution is to use this:

```
javac --class-path  ../  file.java
```

**Or go 1 level up to `/work/*` and run:**

```
javac  ./packageName/Member.java
```

Or simply use `java` instead of `javac` to execute.

Answer (score 0):

if java file contains "project", descent and run java package.class (package name = parent dir name)
else run it from same directory (I'd say normally)
#beware empty spaces, and such, not perfect ...

```
package=""
package=`cat $java_file | grep package | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;//g'`
path_p="."
[[ ! -z $package ]] && class_p="$package.$class" && path_p=".."   # ;)

cd $path_p
java $class_p
```

Answer (score -2):

You should compile it first by typing this command in CMD, for exemple your file is in c:\ directory :

```
C:\com>javac HelloWorld.java
```

After that you can run the result by typing:

```
c:\com>java HelloWorld
```