# No main type error in java

Tags: java

This is the source code:

```
package feetToInches2;

public class Feet2Inches {
    private double feetToInches_(double feet) {
        return 12* feet;    
    } 

    private int max(int val1 int val2) {
        if (val1 > val2) {
        } else {
            return (val2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, it says "Selection does not contain main type". I have asked my professor and he says sometimes eclipse does that and all I need to do is restart my computer. Is that true?

Comment: What is the entry point of a java program?

Comment: You're missing a "public static void main(String ... args)" method.

Comment: As the message say you miss the method names main `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Comment: Where's the ```Selection``` you speak of?

Comment: You had not define the main() inside of the class. When you run a java application, JVM is seeking main() to run the application.Define the main() and run the application. Also you had not define the body of the   if.

Comment: If you think about it a little, what do you expect to happen? Run `max()` or `feetToInches()`? With what parameters? Java needs an entry point, where your program can start, and for that you need a static `main()` method.

Comment: Either your professor is trying to make a joke of you, or you did not post all of your code. Btw. if you are using Eclipse, open your class, and pres `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`. It will reformat your code to a form, that java programmers like it ;)

Comment: There is no `public` method in this class.

Comment: if I add public static void main(String[] args) { after public class Feet2Inches { it gives me an error ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a main method. It is an entry point

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your code here
}
```

in your case it can look like:

```
package feetToInches2;


public class Feet2Inches {
    public double feetToInches_ (double feet) {
        return 12* feet;    
    } 

    public int max(int val1, int val2) {
        if (val1 > val2) {
            return (val1);
        } 
        else {
            return (val2);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Feet2Inches converter=new Feet2Inches();
        int max = converter.max(100,50);
        double inches = converter.feetToInches_(10.5);
        System.out.println("Max value = " + max);
        System.out.println("Inches = " + inches);
    }

}
```

i've changed your method modifiers so it would be more usefull. Class with no public method is unneeded class ;) I also fixed some of errors in your code.

**EDIT:**

If you want to allow people to youse your code to their own calculation you have two choises. You can take parameters from `args` array which holds parameters that was program runned with. or you can prompt for a data at the runtime.

**1 Using parameters**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Feet2Inches converter = new Feet2Inches();
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.err.println("Missing arguments! give me three numbers");
        System.exit(1);//error exit
    }
    int val1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    int val2 = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    double val3 = Double.valueOf(args[1]);
    int max = converter.max(val1, val2);
    double inches = converter.feetToInches_(val3);
    System.out.println("Max value from (" + val1 + "," + val2 + ")= " + max);
    System.out.println(val3 + "Feet = " + inches + " inches");
}
```

now you have to call your program with arguments [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139756/how-to-run-a-class-file-that-is-part-of-a-package-from-cmd) you can see how to do it from cmd and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222153/eclipse-how-we-take-arguments-for-main-when-run) is how to do it in Eclipse

**2 ask user for parameters at runtime**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Feet2Inches converter = new Feet2Inches();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Argument 1:");
    int val1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Argument 2:");
    int val2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Argument 3:");
    double val3 = input.nextDouble();
    int max = converter.max(val1, val2);
    double inches = converter.feetToInches_(val3);
    System.out.println("Max value from (" + val1 + "," + val2 + ")= " + max);
    System.out.println(val3 + "Feet = " + inches + " inches");
}
```

Comment: So I copied and tried to run the code you have written but it says for max and inches "The value of the local variable max is not used"

Comment: yes, it is correct. i assigned an result of your functions to a local variables, but as you see, i dont do much with them. it is up to you what you want to do next. you can for example wtite those results on screen. i'll update my answer so you can see how it works. "The value of the local variable max is not used"  is not an error, its just warning that says hat something is created for no reason. If you have to call a method, that returns some value, and you dont need it (you just need what is happening inside method), then just ignore return value, and dont assign it to any variable.

Comment: thanks a lot. How for example I would want to let someone enter his own numbers and it would convert it for him. Just like a field where he can put the value of inches and it would be converted to feet. When I ran your code this is what have been written in the console: Max value = 100
Inches = 126.0
but there is no way I can edit those fields. I am sorry im just a begginer in Java. Sorry for any stupid quesitons.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
private int max(int val1 int val2)
```

it should be

```
private int max(int val1, int val2)
```

on top of that you a `public static void main(String[] args) {` from which you can call your methods.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a Java Application you always need to have `public static void main(String[] args)` method defined. This method should contain whatever the code you need to execute.

Comment: where exactly should I put it in my code. I have tried after public class Feet2Inches and it doesnt work. It always gives an error.

Comment: It should be inside Feet2Inches class or even could be in a completely different class.