# Could not find or load main class jar intelij

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

After i finished my spring-boot server i want to make it a jar so i can deploy it on a remote server. I choose to do this with maven

After .jar-with-dependecies.jar is created i upload it on server and try to run

```
java -jar buyme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Like everybody else i get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.buyme.BuymeApplication
```

I tried answers from here:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530173/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-error-while-running-java-program-using-cmd-p)

[Link 4](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html#axzz4j8AZh9vp)

Nothing seems to work. 
This is my

> pom.xml

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <mainClass>com.buyme.BuymeApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.buyme.BuymeApplication
```

> This is the project structure

[image]

> mvn commands:

```
mvnc clean install (sometimes i tried assembly:assembly with the other two)
```

This doesn't work either:

```
java -cp <name>.jar com.buyme.BuymeApplication
```

Comment: Is that a full pom.xml? How come I only see the plug-in part?

Comment: As @MinhKieu mentioned, your pom.xml is lacking. Shouldn't you add your dependencies there too?

Comment: @Ishnark - That was what he added above, line #4 and it doesn't work

Comment: Awkward, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I have too many dependencies so it would be pointless to add them here :) i just added what is important.

Comment: Open the JAR and see if your main .class is inside.  Maybe you didn't create a proper fat JAR with all the dependencies inside.  It works if your pom.xml is correct.

Comment: It is inside:
BOOT-INF/classes/com/buyme/BuymeApplication.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it :

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf) answer:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```