# How to run compiled java project from console, not from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After the the demo project is compiled, there are many .class file in the out>production>testPrj>apidemo. Basically, each file will have one .class file

I expect to enter the console:

> java apidemo.class

but it doesn't work.

I tried "java apidemo.class". The error msg is "Error: Could not find or load main class apidemo".

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files). It is not working for my situation. My compile is success, and it can be run from Intellj, but I don't know how to run it from console.   How do I run a compiled java project from console?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the fully qualified name of the class with package name and not include ".class". So you need to place yourself in the parent directory to where `ApiDemo.class` is - i.e. out>production>testPrj.

And then execute:

```
$ java apidemo.ApiDemo
```

Another way is to provide "out/production/testPrj" as the classpath:

```
$ java -cp /path/to/out/production/testPrj apidemo.ApiDemo
```

Comment: got it. Thanks! It is also case sensitive in class name!

Answer (score 3):

For running from console you have to do few things:

- to be sure that your class `apidemo.ApiDemo` has ***main()*** for lunching your program.
- compile sources - navigate to folder where is source file located (it has already compiled by Intellij):

  > javac ApiDemo.java
- run compiled files with `.class` extension, providing ***full class name*** (with packages):

  > java apidemo.ApiDemo

Answer (score 1):

If the class is in a package:

```
package mypackagename;

public class MyClassName {
  public static final void main(String[] cmdLineParams)  {
  } 
}
```

You need to use:

```
java -classpath . MyClassName
```

Notice the "."
It must be called with its fully-qualified name:

```
java -classpath . mypackagename.MyClassName
```