# Running java from the cmd

Tags: java

Trying to run a simple file called Test.java from the cmd. by `javac Test.java` it appears to run, but nothing is printed to the terminal?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
            Integer a = 1000, b = 1000;  
            System.out.println(a == b);
            Integer c = 100, d = 100;  
            System.out.println(c == d); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run Java .class files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile and run your class Test.java you should do this.

```
javac Test.java --to compile
```

and

```
java Test  -- to run
```

you can take a look at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Answer (score 2):

javac will compile the file, you need to run it by `java Test`

Executing javac will only create the compiled bytecode file, named `Test.class`

Answer (score 2):

The javac command in Java compiles a program from a command prompt.

```
javac Test.java
```

Since nothing is printed to the terminal, we will assume it did not have any errors.

The java command from a command prompt runs the program.

```
java Test
```