# Command line to run a java program

Tags: java, class, command-line, classnotfoundexception

I finished my java project in Eclipse (and it works) and I would like to run it on a server. I put the `.class` files from the "target" directory to my server. Then I tried to run it by using the command:

```
java myPackage.Main
```

But I get a `"Class myPackag.Main Not found"` error.
I specified the path in the `CLASSPATH` variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how did you specified CLASSPATH?

Comment: Can you show us your directory structure and your manifest file? Also how are you running the program?

Comment: You mispelled `myPackag`. It should be `myPackage`.

Comment: If the error message you posted is correct, then Brandon is correct, and this is a simple typo in the string you used on the servers command line.

Comment: I mispelled only here sorry, i used the command :

Comment: java myPackage.Main

Comment: Well, then you study that "duplicate" link ... it something around that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files