# How to resolve error Could not find or load main class error in command prompt?

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to run a java code in command prompt. I have the java file in a folder abc in D drive. I have 2 jars also in the same folder. Compilation is done. Class file is created within the folder abc. When trying to execute it using java command, I am getting error "could not find or load main class". Could someone please help me?
I am using the below command in cmd:
java -cp D:/Java_mail/javax.mail.jar;D:/Java_mail/activation.jar Emailfetch

Comment: use `java -jar`

Comment: Add content, of your class that contains the "public static main" method.

Comment: @Lino could you please elaborate?

Comment: Perhaps this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run a JAR file, you must have your jar as runnable. It means you must have a class in it that has

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Otherwise you will not be able to run it.