# javac and JVM are the same? can I execute a file.class only using JRE and not JDK? how can I do it on Windows?

Tags: java, jar

I've read a lot of articles about java and the WORE ("write once and run everywhere"), but i have a doubt since they say that you can compile a file.java into a file.class and run this .class file anywhere but after installing JRE in my Windows 10 and try to run a file.class wich contains a simple "hello word" nothing happens, is it that i need to use a jar file with the JRE instead of only using file.class?
I wanna do this without using the JDK and the "java" command only using JRE or do I have to do something else I'm missing with the FILE.class?

Comment: Please shows us exactly what you did, and what the (error) output was (a [mre])

Comment: I've already solve this problem, it was because I haven't set the globla variables on windows, that was the main thing I was missing, and in fact the JRE and JDK have the JVM it's just that the JRE doesn't have the java compiler ("javac") and with both JDK and JRE I can run a file.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> javac and JVM are the same?

No.

Not even close.  `javac` is the Java compiler.  The JVM means "Java Virtual Machine" ... and you get one whenever you run the `java` command.

NB:  `javac` and `java` (or `javaw`) are different programs.  Don't confuse them.

> can I execute a file.class only using JRE and not JDK?

Yes.  However, from Java 9 onwards you can't get a (just) JRE distribution from Oracle anymore.  It is JDKs ... or nothing.

> how can I do it on Windows?

Lots of ways.  See  [How do I run Java .class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files) for more information.

> .... after installing JRE in my Windows 10 and try to run a file.class wich contains a simple "hello word" nothing happens

Then you've done something wrong.  See the above link.  Or **carefully** read the Oracle Java [Getting Started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) tutorial and follow the instructions therein.

> Is it that I need to use a jar file with the JRE instead of only using file.class?

No.  You don't need a JAR file for a "hello world" class.  You just need to read and follow the instructions.

> I wanna do this without using the JDK and the "java" command only using JRE ...

(I think you mean the `javac` command.  Because the `java` command is in both JRE and JDK distributions.)

From Java 9 onwards you won't be able to do that; see above.

However, from Java 8 onwards there are alternatives that don't involve installing a JRE or a JDK.  Once you have figured out how to run your ".class" file using the `java` command, do some research on `jlink` ... which allows you to create stand-alone executables.  But note these executables are NOT "write once, run everywhere": they are platform specific.

Comment: Thank you Stephen C your answer was very useful cause now I know that I have JVM in both JRE and JDK, it's just a matter of setting the global variables on Windows and you can use "java" comand only with JRE with a .class file.