# Why I am getting Error: Could not find or load main class A Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:?

Tags: java, terminal, java-17

I was trying to run a java program from terminal. So I compiled the code using `javac FileName.java` and then tried to execute that by `java ClassName` and also tried `java ClassName.class`. I am trying very basic code like printing 'Hello World' and the java file is not inside any packages also. But in Command line it is throwing error like :
[image]

But in the folder class file is being generated.

Can anyone help me what is the problem?

I tried to uninstall and reinstall java SE 17 (jdk 17.0.1) but it is still not working. And one more thing is that if I try to run that through VS Code or any code editor it is properly running there.

A.java File:-

```
import java.util.*;

public class A
{
    static public void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two number: ");
        int n1,n2;
        n1 = sc.nextInt();
        n2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Sum of "+n1+" and "+n2+" is equal to : "+(n1+n2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `A.java` file?

Comment: You aren't running it correctly. Read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files

Comment: @kgiannakakis yes, he is

Comment: Probably the folder you are in, is not in the classpath

Comment: Have you declared A in a package? what is the classpath?

Comment: A is not in a package, so I guess that you're classpath does not include the current directory (`E:/Sem 7/JavaCodes`).

Comment: Try `java -cp . A`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Classpath wasn't set.

Comment: That's odd. I thought the class-path always defaulted to the working directory if not explicitly set...

Comment: @Slaw unless a `CLASSPATH` variable is set, which we can’t recognize from what the OP has shown. Side note to the OP: a program as simple as this can also be run using just `java A.java` which will compile and run it in one go, without any class path.